# Will the election guarantee we will have non-overlapping moderators?

Tags: discussion, election

see the [election for moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4) that is currently open.

Here are some key points:

- There are only 4 positions available,
- Not everyone is interested in all tags,
- Some are even "specialized" in some areas.

How do we ensure we don't get 4 more moderators that will overlap in their interests and focus on only a couple of tags (e.g. [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript))?

Comment: We don't. Simple as that.

Comment: I think this is an important point that has been overlooked.

Comment: Isn't this what voting is for? If you think this is important, vote for someone who doesn't know PHP.

Comment: Don't forget that there are [other moderators](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) already in place as well.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Moderators are expected to moderate the entire site, not only a single (or few) tags, even if that's where they feel more comfortable.

It doesn't really matter where you're best at answering, moderation isn't about technical accuracy problems anyway. It's about moderation problems, problems that cannot be handled by the community, which includes people active on that tag.

I don't see a very big problem with that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too concerned about which tags or specializations the candidates have listed. If they have actively demonstrated:

1. a strong interest in the overall health of the SE community and
2. some background that indicates moderation skill/potential,

then it seems reasonable to consider them potential moderator material. Everything else comes second in my book.